# ¿Cómo muevo un elemento k de una lista a la parte derecha de la misma en un mismo ciclo de python?

Tags: python

Tengo una `lista=[2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]` el problema consiste en mover todos los ceros a la derecha y que los demás elementos me queden en el mismo orden, sin necesidad de crear otra lista; es decir, que la `lista=[2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]` original se reescriba de esta forma `lista=[2,3,4,5,5,0,0,0,0]`.

Utilizando un solo código:

```
lista = [2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]
for x in lista:
  if x !=0:
    lista = lista[x:]
  print (lista)
```

Comment: Hola Aurelio, te invito a hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 2):

Sin crear una nueva lista, simplemente intercambiando elementos dentro de la lista existente:

```
def ordenar(lista):
    start = 0  # Primer elemento a examinar.
    stop = len(lista) - 1 # Ultimo elemento por examinar

    while start < stop:
        if lista[start] == 0:
            #   Buscar el ultimo elemento no cero
            #   a la derecha.
            while lista[stop] == 0 and stop > start:
                stop -= 1
            #   Si hay un último elemento, intercambiar
            #   y correr la marca final.
            if stop > start:
                lista[stop], lista[start] = lista[start], lista[stop]
                stop -= 1
        start += 1
    return lista
```

La idea es que estamos ordenando los elementos entre start y stop, ninguno de los cuales ha sido revisado antes. En el momento que start >= stop, significa que ya revisamos todos y podemos terminar.

En el ciclo avanzados con start hasta detectar un elemento en cero. Luego retrocemos con stop hasta detectar uno que no sea cero y ahi hacemos el intercambio.

#### Demo

```
lista=[2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]

def ordenar(lista):
    start = 0  # Primer elemento a examinar.
    stop = len(lista) - 1 # Ultimo elemento por examinar

    while start < stop:
        if lista[start] == 0:
            #   Buscar el ultimo elemento no cero
            #   a la derecha.
            while lista[stop] == 0 and stop > start:
                stop -= 1
            #   Si hay un último elemento, intercambiar
            #   y correr la marca final.
            if stop > start:
                lista[stop], lista[start] = lista[start], lista[stop]
                stop -= 1
        start += 1
    return lista

print(ordenar(lista))
print(ordenar([1,2,3]))
```

produce:

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Es una petición muy extraña, ¿por qué esa imposición de que no haya que crear otra lista?

Podría resolverse fácilmente así:

```
lista = [x for x in lista if x!=0] + [0] * lista.count(0)
```

pero esto sí que estaría creando otra lista (la comprehension crea una lista nueva, en la que ya no hay ceros, y luego añado al final otra lista repitiendo [0] tantas veces como ceros había en la lista original)

Se puede comprobar que la lista ya no es la misma porque varía el id al que apunta la variable `lista`:

```
lista=[2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]
print("Antes:  ", id(lista), lista)
lista = [x for x in lista if x!=0] + [0] * lista.count(0)
print("Después:", id(lista), lista)
```

Sale:

```
Antes:   140296455972800 [2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0]
Después: 140296457072384 [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Si lo que necesitas es que no varíe el id de la lista, puedes usar el siguiente truco:

```
lista=[2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]
print("Antes:  ", id(lista), lista)
lista[:] = [x for x in lista if x!=0] + [0] * lista.count(0)
print("Después:", id(lista), lista)
```

que hace lo mismo que antes, pero en vez de reasignar el identificador `lista` para que apunte a la nueva lista, lo que hace es reasignar todos los **elementos** de `lista` cambiándolos por los especificados en el resultado, pero sin variar el lugar a que apuntaba. Mira como el id se mantiene:

```
Antes:   140296456101824 [2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0]
Después: 140296456101824 [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Si lo que quieres es que no varíe el identifica

Answer (score 1):

#### Analizando el escenario

Es muy probable que sea un ejercicio de clase, por que en un escenario real, es mucho más facil armar una nueva lista. Pero aun así es interesante y acepté el reto.

Al usar usar slices, comprensión de lista y ciertas operaciones, creamos implicitamente una nueva lista, por lo que no podemos usar estas cosas.

Tampoco nos sirve iterar sobre la lista original y modificarla. Esto lleva a comportamientos inesperados (probablemente por que el contador interno que usa el iterador no se actualiza).

#### Solución

Esto me llevó al siguiente código:

```
import random

lista = [random.randrange(5) for _ in range(10)]

print("Antes", lista)
print("Id", id(lista))
print()

contador = 0
end = len(lista) - 1

while contador <= end:
    if(lista[contador] == 0):
        lista.append(lista.pop(contador))
        end -= 1
    else:
        contador += 1

print("Despues", lista)
print("Id", id(lista))
```

Que produce

```
Antes [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2]
Id 56855688

Despues [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Id 56855688
```

**explicación**

El plan es ejecutar el código hasta que el contador alcance el final.

Entonces, si:

- El numero actual es 0: usamos pop para eliminar y obtener el elemento en la posición actual y lo agregamos al final de la lista. Finalmente, como es seguro que el ultimo numero del end es 0, disminuimos en 1 el end para que no se revise esa parte al cohete. NO aumentamos el contador, por que habiendo movido el 0, el elemento siguiente está en la misma posición que aquel 0 que movimos.
- En caso contrario: simplemente aumentamos en uno el contador para avanzar con el siguiente elemento.

Como podrás ver al final, las ids son las mismas, lo que significa que la variable lista señala a la misma lista antes y después.

Comment: Apostaría que intercambiar los elementos es más eficiente que usar append/pop

Comment: @CandidMoe Intercambiar con respecto a que?

Comment: Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: Tu respuesta va de adelante para atras, avanza 1 y repite. Preferiría evitar eso por temas de eficiencia @CandidMoe

Answer (score 1):

Añado otra respuesta, sólo por completar a las ya dadas. En esta ocasión empleo el propio método de ordenación de listas, creando una función de ordenación específica con el criterio indicado:

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key

@cmp_to_key
def compare(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    if x == 0:
        return 1   # x se mueve a la derecha
    elif y == 0:
        return -1  # y se mueve a la derecha
    else:
        return 0   # no se cambia el orden

lista.sort(key=compare)
```

---

**Edición**: variante sin usar `cmp`

De los comentarios, se puede hacer mejor sin usar una función de comparación `cmp`, tan sólo con la recomendada función `key`:

```py
lista.sort(key=lambda x: 0 if x else 1))  # @abulafia
```

```py
lista.sort(key=lambda x: not x)
```

```py
lista.sort(key=lambda x: -bool(x))
```

Comment: ¡qué buena idea! solo que no me gusta usar la lógica de cmp, prefiero la de key. Se podría lograr con la misteriosa expresión siguiente: `lista.sort(key=lambda x: 0 if x else 1)`

Comment: Tienes razón, habría que evitar el `cmp` en python siempre que se pueda. Otras formas de hacer más _misteriosa_  la `key` podrían ser `lista.sort(key=lambda x: not x)` o `lista.sort(key=lambda x: -bool(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

Ante las excelentes respuestas de los "grandes", me costó decidir si agregar mi respuesta, finalmente me decidí, por el solo hecho de que es "cortita".

```
lista = [ 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0 ]

k = 0
for i in range( len( lista )):
  if lista[ i - k ] == 0:
    del lista[ i - k ]
    lista.append( 0 )
    k += 1
    
print( lista )
```

Con la variable ***k***, lo que hacemos es desacoplar el contador del for, del indice con el cual recorremos el array, básicamente, cada vez que quitamos un valor,**k** aumenta, por lo que en la próxima iteración, ""caemos"" en la misma posición de la anterior iteración.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [2,3,0,4,5,0,0,5,0]

i = 0
j = len(lista) - 1
while i < j:
  if lista[i] == 0:
    lista.pop(i)
    lista.append(0)
    j -= 1
  else:
    i += 1

print(lista)
```

Podrías hacerlo utilizando dos índices, `i` y `j`, uno para recorrer la lista desde el principio y el otro para recorrerla desde el final. Si el elemento en la posición `i` es igual a 0, se elimina de la lista y se agrega al final de la lista. Si no es 0, entonces se mueve el índice `i` hacia la derecha. Este proceso se repite hasta que `i` sea mayor o igual a `j`.